# Why should I use custom Open Graph Sponsored Stories

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-ads-api

Facebook allows me to create a creative which targets an open graph actions, such as:
"User listened to a song on Spotify".

Why should my creative target an object which isn't mine?
Can someone bring up a useful example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you may want to target a band.

You don't have to own the app in order to promote the band.

For example: "John has listened to 'The black Keys' on Spotify".
That way you can target and promote the band even if you don't own the app or the object.